# How to write a for loop without variable?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, increment

I want to write a for loop directly without any variable. Is it possible?

Example:

```
for (1; 1 <= 4; ++) {
  printf ("Loop working\n");
}
```

Expected output:

```
Loop working
Loop working
Loop working
Loop working
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++11 range-based for loops without loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711655/c11-range-based-for-loops-without-loop-variable)

Comment: Why would someone want to do that? Unless initialized, it would be an infinite loop. When you want it to iterate over 4 times, let it know that way.

Comment: Well you need a variable to keep the iteration count. Without a count you can only get an infinite loop.

Comment: is loop unrolling an option ? (possibly [aided with macro's or template functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231743/self-unrolling-macro-loop-in-c-c))

Comment: Avoid tagging both C and C++

Comment: What problem are you _actually_  trying to resolve? This could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @WedaPashi -- this would mean "do this four times", without the distraction of having to name a loop-control variable, and perhaps without the distraction of some compiler writer complaining that you created a variable that you never used.

Comment: @PeteBecker: True that. But I am trying to foresee a use-case for one such implementation..

Answer (score 2):

You need a variable to keep count, but you can hide it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define JOIN(a, b) (a ## b)
// WARNING: don't LOOP in the same line
#define LOOP(n) for (unsigned JOIN(HIDDEN, __LINE__) = 0; JOIN(HIDDEN, __LINE__) < n; JOIN(HIDDEN, __LINE__)++)

int main(void) {
    LOOP(4) {
        printf("foo");
        LOOP(2) printf(" bar");
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[See code running on ideone](https://ideone.com/q48RsZ)

Output

```
foo bar bar
foo bar bar
foo bar bar
foo bar bar
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
for(; ;);
```

But this will be an infinite loop. Add a break statement and it will run only once

```
for(; ; )
    break;
```

Or you can use increment and conditional statements inside the loop

```
int i = 0;

for(; ;){
    printf ("Loop working\n");
    ++i;
    if( i >= 4)
        break;
}
```

Comment: same as `while(1){}`

Comment: Or better yet, `while(true);` ;-)

Comment: I don't want an infinite loop. Just print "Loop working " (4 times). How to increment?

Comment: Yes. But he is interested in `for`!

Comment: OP wants no variable

Comment: @Stoogy; What if OP wants to compile the program without any compiler?

Comment: @Biswajit if you want to loop only 4 times, you ought to specify that in the question.

Comment: @Biswajit "How to increment?" Increment what?  You have no variable!

Comment: @WilliamPursell I already specify that (I want 4 iterations) inside loop. Yes! there is no variable that's why I am asking here.

Comment: @Biswajit No, you did not specify.  You asked a very generic question, and provided an example that happened to iterate 4 times.

Answer (score -1):

To have the loop terminate, you need to keep state which says at which point you are.

Usually, you use loop variable for this.

You can also use recursion, in which case the state is encoded differently, but still needed:

```cpp
void loop(int i)
{
    if (i < 4) {
        printf ("Loop working\n");
        loop(++i); // recursive call
    }
}

int main()
{
    loop(0);
}
```